# Limit IE 11 to a whitelist while still permitting other browsers to access all sites

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

We are attempting to kill off IE in our environment, because it renders poorly on many (most) websites and is a general headache. However we still need it because of a few legacy applications. Thus, we'd like to only allow IE to access a whitelisted set of sites. Other browsers (Chrome/Firefox/etc.) should not be restricted by this policy. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Environment:

Nonprofit doing basic science research. 250 users, with 600 or so workstations/laptops and Servers across 3 sites. Mixed OS (Mac, Linux, Windows) with 2, password synced, directories (OpenLDAP and AD). Servers are about 80-90% virtualized on VMware vSphere 6 cluster, backed by NetApp. HPC Cluster backed by Isilon storage for projects, which also contains the majority of department fileshares.

Configuration Management:

Group Policy, ARD, Altiris 7.1 and the beginnings of Chef. Basic Science research equipment necessitates Windows machinery to run, and costs prohibit regular replacements, leaving us with a few Windows XP SP3 and 1 or 2 SP2's still on network, though firewalled from the Internet.

Comment: So, what is your "environment"? What computers are there? What type of control do you have? Central administration, admin rights for users, central configuration management...

Comment: Also, why do you want to "kill off IE"? It is still supported, so it's going nowhere in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for the information. In the future, please add it directly to your question. I've done that for you this time.

Comment: The simple answer is likely going to be that you can't. Assuming you're using a proxy you might be able to do some fancy filtering on the user agent. Chrome uses the same proxy settings as IE as far as I know, so you can't simply get rid of the proxy for chrome. If you're running IE without some IE7 compatibility mode GPO it should be pretty OK from my experience. So maybe check what you have configured as settings for IE as well?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is no official, supported way to set up a "site whitelist" in Internet Explorer, i.e. to restrict IE to a specific list of sites. You can cook up something yourself, but you'll have to decide whether that is worth the hassle for you.

- One option is to create a makeshift whitelist using a proxy auto-configuration (PAC) file. The idea is basically to set up a proxy configuration that redirects all non-whitelisted sites to `localhost`, effectively blocking them. See e.g. [Web Site Whitelisting in Microsoft Internet Explorer](https://security.berkeley.edu/resources/best-practices-how-articles/web-site-whitelisting-microsoft-internet-explorer) for detailed instructions.
- Another option would be to somewhat hide IE, by removing it from the Start Menu and the Taskbar. Instead, add Start Menu entries to launch IE to a specific site, one for each site that needs IE. That way users are discouraged (though not prevented) from using IE for regular browsing, but can still use it for the sites where it's necessary.

Ultimately, there will probably be no foolproof technical solution. The best approach will probably be to inform your users, just as in your question, that use of IE is discouraged, and that it will be removed once all the legacy applications have been converted (you *are* working on this, aren't you?).